# Karma loads some of my js files to the browser as minified version

Tags: javascript, jasmine, karma-runner, karma-jasmine, minify

I have an angular project in which I write in ECMAScript 6. Therefore, I have some tools to build my project (using gulp, babel, etc...).
When I load the project all the files are loaded correctly (after being compiled to my needs).

However, when I test it, my test files load correctly but the build files are kind of wierdly minified.
It only happens in my computer. My team has same WebStorm version (11.03), same Chrome (47.0.2526) same Windows 7 and same Karma config file. In their computers it all loads perfectly.

Any ideas where the bug comes from? Thx in advance :)

***Update:***

As I work with different teams, the karma configuration file was setup correctly but their dependencies (of the Preprocessors plugins) weren't up to date.

Comment: Goldy, this may not be a bug at all. There is a possibility that your files are cashed by the browser. If you have not disabled the cash while debugging, or you are not using some type of cash busting, then you are looking at old files.

Comment: And by cash I mean cache, and cashed means cached.

Comment: @WilmerSaint I checked it out. that wasn't the problem. I found the problem was in the Preprocessors configuration. Thanks anyway and I'll update my question.